# Facebook Login Button not Changing to Logout button Immediate after Login in swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, xcode9.2

I am Working on Xcode 9.2 Swift 4.0 using FacebookSDKs-iOS-20160316 for Facebook Login Authentication Integration . My storyboard is empty .

On Running

Facebook Login button is coming on an app

When clicked Facebook login page comes, after successful login

Permission for my app is asked, When allowed following page comes

[Page after allowing access to my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0Phz.png)

When I click on done button of this page

I am redirected to my storyboard , and this time also same login button is there , my login button is not changed to Logout. On clicking it again following page comes:
[After clicking Login button again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0R6q.png)
This is happening every Time. Please help me.

Things I have tried:

Restarted the Simulator

Restarted the Xcode

Changed Simulator

```
//My View Controller is having code:

class ViewController: UIViewController,FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate{

func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithresult:     
FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) 
 {
 print("Logged in")
 }
    func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) 
{
    print("Logged out")
}

let loginManager: FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
override func viewDidLoad() 
  {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let button = FBSDKLoginButton()
    button.center = self.view.center
    self.view.addSubview(button)
    button.delegate = self
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this function as for logout along with login.

```
func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
        print("User is looged out")
    }
```